# Парсинг текста на C#

Tags: c#, парсер

Есть такая проблема: когда делаю построчный парсинг .txt файла при помощи рег. выражений, проверяет только 1 строку но не переходит дальше. Вот код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"D:\parse test\prs.txt";
    Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        RegexOptions ignoreCase = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"^\s+[0-9]", ignoreCase);
        Match m = reg.Match(line);
        while (line != null)
        {
            if(m.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                m = m.NextMatch();

            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Что не так?

Comment: while (line != null) это не чтение строки. вы вечно проверяете. но никогда не читаете следующую строку.

Comment: @vitidev как тогда переходить на следующую строку?

Comment: line = sr.ReadLine();

Comment: Перенесите ReadLine в тело цикла, сейчас у вас бесуонечный цикл, так как переменная line не меняется. И вместо ReadLine и StreamReader можно использовать одну функцию ReadLines https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd383357(v=vs.110).aspx и foreach

Comment: @PrimusSingularis спасибо, помогло

Answer (score -1):

взято отсюда [Метанит](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/5.5.php)

```
 string path= @"C:\SomeDir\hta.txt";

try
{
    Console.WriteLine("******считываем весь файл********");
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("******считываем построчно********");
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("******считываем блоками********");
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
    {
        char[] array = new char[4];
        // считываем 4 символа
        sr.Read(array, 0, 4);

        Console.WriteLine(array);           
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Не занимайтесь велосипедизмом, есть стандартная функция File.ReadLines, и File.ReadAllLines